# Microsoft Bot Framework bots disappeared

Tags: botframework

Since a few days we are missing our bots in the "My Bots" section of the Microsoft Bot Framework at https://dev.botframework.com/

They still do work as expected, but we can not see or edit them. Maybe there is any way to list them without the website?

Creation of new bots seems to work fine, but if the old ones are lost, this would be really bad.

Does anyone know how to recover them or if there was/is some kind of maintenance? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: Which version of framework you were using?

Comment: Add another bot to the list. the previous one will be showed!

Comment: @Just Shadow 3.0 and high-speed storage were checked, aswell as the old one which was greyed out and checked

Comment: @OmG i just created another "test"-bot, and the old ones still do not sow up sadly

Comment: It's just a bug! now remove the the test bot! I have the same problem! By adding and removing the test bot you might find the previous bot.

Comment: @OmG this does not seem to work :( I also found that cached URL's to our bots do not work anymore. It looks like https://dev.botframework.com/bots?id=botname and works for newly created bots but not for the old ones. Any other ideas? Thanks again

Comment: I would advise checking in another browser (in case you haven't already) and if they still don't show up then report an issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues looks like the best place.

Comment: @stuartd Other browser & devices did not help, the issue will be reported elsewhere as u suggested. Thanks for the tips

Comment: We're actively looking into this.  I will update you when we have more information.

Comment: Hi @LIL_D - Please report this issue on [Microsoft/BotBuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/new) repository and include the bot name, bot handle and App ID of the affected bots.

Comment: @NilsW https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3167

Comment: @JasonSowers thanks for your help